# Elegant way to detect current provider int web3.js

Tags: web3js, mist, parity, metamask, infura

I want to know what provider the user is using (Metamaks, Mist...)so I can give better user experience.  ***E.g.*** Give tips on how to unlock an account

I'm currently doing this, but is far from elegant. Is there a more correct/reliable way achieve the same?

```
getProviderName=()=>
{
    let providerName = "UNKNOWN"

    if(window.web3.currentProvider.constructor.name === "MetamaskInpageProvider")        
        providerName = "METAMASK"

    else if(window.web3.currentProvider.constructor.name === "EthereumProvider")        
        providerName = "MIST"

    else if(window.web3.currentProvider.constructor.name === "o")        
        providerName = "PARITY"

    else if(window.web3.currentProvider.host.indexOf("infura")!==-1) 
        providerName = "INFURA"      

    else if(window.web3.currentProvider.host.indexOf("localhost")!==-1)  
        providerName ="LOCALHOST"

    return providerName
}
```

Comment: Interesting that a few years on and there is no real elegant solution? Also nobody mentioned that webpack uglification etc. breaks the `constructor.name` approach, unless classnames are excluding from webpack config.

Answer (score 11):

This my current implementation:

```
getCurrentProvider() {
    if (!window.web3) return 'unknown';

    if (window.web3.currentProvider.isMetaMask)
        return 'metamask';

    if (window.web3.currentProvider.isTrust)
        return 'trust';

    if (window.web3.currentProvider.isGoWallet)
        return 'goWallet';

    if (window.web3.currentProvider.isAlphaWallet)
        return 'alphaWallet';

    if (window.web3.currentProvider.isStatus)
        return 'status';

    if (window.web3.currentProvider.isToshi)
        return 'coinbase';

    if (typeof window.__CIPHER__ !== 'undefined')
        return 'cipher';

    if (window.web3.currentProvider.constructor.name === 'EthereumProvider')
        return 'mist';

    if (window.web3.currentProvider.constructor.name === 'Web3FrameProvider')
        return 'parity';

    if (window.web3.currentProvider.host && window.web3.currentProvider.host.indexOf('infura') !== -1)
        return 'infura';

    if (window.web3.currentProvider.host && window.web3.currentProvider.host.indexOf('localhost') !== -1)
        return 'localhost';

    return 'unknown';
},
```

Comment: Coinbase Wallet currently includes an `isToshi` flag, which may be more appropriate than using the `SOFA` detection strategy.

Comment: this won't work with 1.0.0-beta, use `window.ethereum.isMetaMask` instead

Answer (score 3):

I am looking for a better way myself, at least for metamask I found that you can do that:

window.web3.currentProvider.isMetaMask

Answer (score 1):

MetaMask announced a breaking fix to a security issue that relates to the answer of @Arash Kiani and @mager. When you follow it then you need ...

```
// Modern dapp browsers...
if (window.ethereum) {
    window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
    try {
        // Request account access if needed
        await ethereum.enable();
        // Acccounts now exposed
        web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */});
    } catch (error) {
        // User denied account access...
    }
}
// Legacy dapp browsers...
else if (window.web3) {
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    // Acccounts always exposed
    web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */});
}
```

I only noticed it when investigation the console. The break will be effective from Nov 2 2018!

source: https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

let web3;

if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
  // We are in the browser and metamask is running.
  web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // We are on the server *OR* the user is not running metamask
  const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/foo',
  );
  web3 = new Web3(provider);
}

export default web3;
```

Answer (score 0):

window.web3 has being depreciated, according to the documentation its recommended to use the following:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8546");
console.log(web3.currentProvider.isMetaMask)
```

Comment: This is only for version 1.x of web3

Answer (score 0):

If you are using web3 Modal then you can use  `if(localStorage.getItem('WEB3_CONNECT_CACHED_PROVIDER')!==''){ return localStorage.getItem('WEB3_CONNECT_CACHED_PROVIDER'); }`